# Not able to get HTML content in PHP via jQuery ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, summernote

I am using Summernote text editor. I am collecting HTML in following way:

```
var luck = $(".textEditor").code();
```

my content as of now is as follows :

```
<p><br></p>
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/gallery/1/0336dcbab05b9d5ad24f4333c7658a0e.jpeg" style="width: 640px;"><p>Tell your travel story...</p>
```

I am making following ajax request to send it to PHP

```
 $.ajax({
                 dataType : 'json',
                    async : true,
                    cache : false,
                    beforeSend : function(xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    },
                 data: {
                     'luck' : luck
                 }, 
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/travelogue/postBlog",
                 cache: false,
                 success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                     alert(data);
                 },
                 error:function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     alert(xhr); alert(xhr.status); alert(textStatus);  alert(errorThrown); alert(xhr.statusText); alert(xhr.responseText);                 }
             });
```

on PHP side I am getting data in following way (for example sake I am just puting data in txt file(

```
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fwrite($myfile, $_POST["luck"]);
        fclose($myfile);
```

But I get following content. From IMG tag STYLE tag is missing.

```
<p><br></p><img src="http://127.0.0.1/gallery/1/0336dcbab05b9d5ad24f4333c7658a0e.jpeg"  640px;"><p>Tell your travel story...</p>
```

I am not sure how to retrieve data properly? Is there problem with ajax request or may be i am not getting data in PHP in correct way?

Any suggestions would be helpfull....

Thanks

Comment: Just console log `luck` and see if the style tag is present, if it's not, the plugin you're using is at fault

Comment: yes... style tag is present in console log... its only when I check in PHP that style tag is missing

Comment: Maybe has something to do with this: xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"); if you are specting html should't put this

Comment: The `Accept` header refers to the response data, not the request data.

Comment: @dminones -- I removed it but still problem is not solved...

Comment: To be honest, there are way to many options being used, remove the header stuff, async and cache which you've set twice etc.

Comment: And there's no way jQuery or PHP is removing the style tag, it's probably missing before you send the data

Comment: Check your browser's network panel, is it in the request data?

Comment: @adeneo -- Before making ajax request style tag is present ... but I dont where it is getting lost

Comment: Try logging `typeof luck` and make sure it's a string

Comment: @adeneo - yes i checked it... its a string

Comment: Did you check your browser's network panel? That will tell you for sure what data is being sent to PHP.

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara -- yes i checked it.... javascript is sending correct data

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `file_get_contents(php://input)`. Chances are you'll need to uri encode the html string before sending it, to access it in the post array.